# keep intant values of variable in a constant

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to keep the changing values of a variable for certain times in a constant. For instance, I need to keep the position of a player for a specific action in a constant value in order to use at later times.  I am interested in Java libgdx

Comment: What language are you using? We need more info than that to be any help

Answer (score 0):

For global constants you can create class with constants like this:

```
public class Constants {

// 1 BOX2D meter = 100 pixels;
public static final float PIXELS_PER_METER = 100f;
public static final float BLOCK_SIZE = 90f;
}
```

And then use it in any other call in your game. Like this:

```
Constants.BLOCK_SIZE
```

If you want make the variables changeable, remove `final`, but then it will be not constant.
If you need to create constants for one class just declare them in this class, without `static` identifier.